Sucked into the vacuum of a black hole
is it possible to create same effect in blender and would it work on fully rigged character?
Original


Not as a shader. Use geometry nodes.

@Xana I added an answer.

Mumladze28, welcome to Blender SE! Good question that spurred some useful answers. (Might want to remove the shaders tag, now that we've established that this is not a shader issue.)

thanks!! changed shader tag with geometry-nodes.

Geometry Nodes
Import all the geometry to a new object with the collection info node and realize the instances. The lerp the position of the points (with the Mix Vector node) depending on the distance between each points' position and the position of an empty. You can get the position of an empty with the object info node.
Using a divide node after the distance node, you can adjust for the scale of the empty. I also use a float curve node to control the mix, but a map range node or any combination thereof would work just as well.


Geometry Nodes with a simulation zone
By using a simulation zone you can add some automated acceleration.
The force (and thus acceleration) in gravity is $F = (G * m1 * m2) / d^2$. If you don't care about physically accurate masses you can just use a single constant for $(G * m1 * m2)$.
However, we need to pipe the point offset in from outside of the simulation zone to retain any original animations.


By default, this does not look very impressive.
Here I exaggerated the effect by using increasing the exponent of $d^2$ and animating the constant.

Combine Both
For more artistic control, I would use an animated empty to mark points and then handle them differently in a simulation zone.

I know that this answer is a bit advanced and doesn't explain all the nodes, so feel free to ask in the comments and Incan add details.

thank you so much!! that's exactly what i wanted.

Use a Lattice modifier, if your object is rigged to an armature, just move the armature towards the lattice and it will work:


So simple! I know nothing (again) .. How are things like this exported?

I don't know, does he need to export it?

The ref. comes from Unity.. Just curious.. it can wait.

Cheers @Xana :)

a simple yet effective solution, thank you so much!!

As awesome and versatile as GeoNodes is, it's nice to see people still coming up with innovative ways to use "OG modifiers" like Lattice. :-) BTW, even more fun can be had if you put a Curve modifier on the Lattice object, plus you can make different ShapeKeys for the Lattice to twist it or stretch it as it travels along the curve. Just ideas for people to try out...

@Mentalist sure, it is very improvable   ;)
